# References to the literature in a scientific paper

Tags: expressions

What is a correct way to express an idea in a scientific paper?

> 1) Definition (1) was introduced in [1]. For more details on proofs in this section, see [2] and [3].
>
> 2) Definition (1) was introduced in [1]. For more details on proofs in this section we refer the reader to [2] and [3].

I'm mostly concerned with the expression `details on proofs in this section`.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

"Details of" are unnecessary words. A proof is a proof and is just detailed enough to provide rigour.

In the statistics literature I read it is common practice to put the proofs out of the way somewhere, in the same way that it appears from your example you are trying to do. Most writers simply say:"Proofs are given in ..."

Comment: thank you for the reply! The proofs are complete, I just want to say that there are some papers that give more details on these proofs.

Comment: "Detailed proofs are given in...".